# Regular Expression to match multiple patterns in Php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I try to extract the Cookies from the following String:

```
< Server: Apache
< Set-Cookie: fe_typo_user=b4f33487c434684655dccf65a0499010; path=/
< Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=d8pgb31olkc9c1jc5tc5qn23a1; path=/
< Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
```

Therefore I tried

```
/.*Set-Cookie: (.*?); /s
```

Shouldn't that get me all occurrences of strings between "Set-Cookie: " and ";"?

I received:

```
array(2) {
   [0]=> string(137) \"< Server: Apache
         < Set-Cookie: fe_typo_user=b4f33487c434684655dccf65a0499010; path=/
         < Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=d8pgb31olkc9c1jc5tc5qn23a1; \"
   [1]=> string(36) \"PHPSESSID=d8pgb31olkc9c1jc5tc5qn23a1\"
}
```

Thanks for explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/Set-Cookie: (.*?);/is', $data, $result);
```

Gives:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [0] => Set-Cookie: fe_typo_user=b4f33487c434684655dccf65a0499010;
        [1] => Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=d8pgb31olkc9c1jc5tc5qn23a1;
    )

    [1] => Array
    (
        [0] => fe_typo_user=b4f33487c434684655dccf65a0499010
        [1] => PHPSESSID=d8pgb31olkc9c1jc5tc5qn23a1
    )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the first `.*` and use preg_match_all:

```
preg_match_all('/Set-Cookie: (.*?); /s', $str, $m);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

`/Set\-Cookie:\ ([^;]+);/`

Comment: You don’t need to escape hyphens. Or spaces.